# helm-projectile-find-file-in-known-projects, but with grep

Tags: search

Using helm-projectile-find-file-in-known-projects is great if you know the filename. It searches all known projects for a filename.

, but what if you want to search for a string one of the files contains?

Is there some function for that?;)

Also, searching org-mode headlines across all projects would also be nice;)

Answer (score 0):

That should be as simple as:

```lisp
(helm-do-grep-1 (projectile-all-project-files))
```

However, that will probably spawn way too many `grep` processes, so it may be smarter to do:

```lisp
(helm-do-grep-1 projectile-known-projects 'recurse)
```

Which will have the drawback of not respecting VC-ignored files.

Comment: Not sure I understand how to call this?